# automatic generation of flowchart

Tags: jsp, flowchart

I would like to generate flow chart from a list of steps. For example

1. do x.
2. check y.
3. if true go to z
4. else finish.

Could you guys help me with this. A sample java code would be great. Thanx in advance.

Btw it should support ie8.

Comment: Have you tried using Graphviz?  [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115870/creating-straight-edges-in-graphviz)

Comment: Nope... I will check Graphviz... Thank you

Comment: by using graphviz i can draw graph but not flowchart...
any other solution?

Comment: basically I needed to draw on internet explorer 8 I forgot to mention that in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very good javascript library by which one can easily draw flow chart from plain text.... I thought it might help some one to share the library...
here is the link....

1. New: http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/ [old: http://raphaeljs.com/]

for additional help please go through the tutorials...

2. http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php

Comment: Link appears to be dead.

Comment: Hi, I have added the new link.